# Object sharing between threads produces NoneType

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

**Background:**

I'm working on a web crawler that spawns 7 threads, each to query a unique URL for an XML file. When each query receives a response, it turns that response into an XML tree like so:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host = uHost, port = uPort)
conn.request('GET', url = '/some/url/file.xml')
resp = conn.getresponse()
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(resp)
```

When each thread is started, it is given a `queue.Queue()` as an argument, so that it may put the `tree` into it so that `__main__` is the only thread writing files. Continuing from above:

**__main__**

```
def receive(q):
    while True:
        try:
            uTree = q.get()
            uTree.write('/some/path/file.xml')
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
```

**spawned**

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host = uHost, port = uPort)
conn.request('GET', url = '/some/url/file.xml')
resp = conn.getresponse()
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(resp)
q.put_nowait(tree)
```

However, I started receiving `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'` when calling `uTree.write()`. A quick change of `uTree.write()` to `print(type(uTree))` showed that objects would sometimes remain intact, other times they become `NoneType`:

```
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree'>
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree'>
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree'>
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree'>
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree'>
```

**Questions:**

Why are objects passed from a `threading.Thread()` to a `queue.Queue()` [residing on `__main__`] changing to `NoneType` inconsistently?

How can I resolve this?

**Full Code (if needed):**

**main.py**

```
import queue
import crawl # custom module
import threading

def crawler(query):
    while True:
        try:
            query.connect()
            break
        except:
            pass

def receive(q):
    while True:
        try:
            uQuery = q.get()
            uTree = uQuery.tree
            uTree.write('/some/path/file.xml')
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

urls = ['/url1.xml', '/url2.xml', ...]

q = queue.Queue()

queries = [Query(url, q) for url in urls]
threads = [threading.Thread(target = crawler, args = (query,)) for query in queres]

for t in threads:
    t.start()

receive(q)
```

**crawl.py**

```
import http.client
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Query:
    def __init__(self, url, q):
        self.url = url
        self.queue = q
        self.tree = None

    def connect():
        conn = http.Client.HTTPConnect(host = 'something.com', port = '80')
        conn.request('GET', url = self.url)
        resp = conn.getresponse()
        self.tree = ET.parse(resp)
        self.queue.put_nowait(self)
        conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

(I'd comment but don't seem to have the reputation)

This is not solving your issue but may give you some pointers.

I know it is more difficult to debug threading issues but I would suggest to simplify your example. You are including parsing of XML using ElementTree and HTTP connections - both don't seem to be relevant to the question.

To solve your issue you might also gain insights from logging what you are putting into the queue.

I would advice to be extra careful when putting complex objects, such as a parsed tree, into the queue. You would then need to make sure that the kind of object is itself thread-safe.

In case you are not aware of it, I'd recommend using https://scrapy.org/ which would make implementing a crawler so much easier.